# Open folder and maximise the folder window

Tags: powershell

I have the following simple Powershell script:

```
ii E:\Source\Development\websites\example.com.au\root
ii E:\Source\Development\websites\example.com.au
ii E:\Source\Development\websites\example.com.au\css
ii E:\Source\Development\websites\example.com.au\database
ii E:\Source\Development\websites\example.com.au\js
```

However, when the folder windows open, they are often not maximised at full screen. I have to manually click on each folder's window and then select 'Maximize' off the window's menu. This is annoying for scripts that are much longer than the example shown (e.g. 20 plus windows). Does anyone know to maximise these folder windows using powershell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use AppActivate method, don't forget to send Enter key to gain focus, then Alt Spacebar X ("% X") to maximize.

```
$folder = "C:\Temp"
ii $folder
Start-Sleep -m 100
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.VisualBasic')
[Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::AppActivate("$folder")
Start-Sleep -m 100
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Windows.Forms')
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{ENTER}")
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("% X")
```

Wrap a loop and you are all set.

Comment: This is what I am after. It does what I need. The only small issue is that it is not a clean solution as there is an exception error each time a file is opened. - Error Message `Exception calling "AppActivate" with "1" argument(s): "Process 'E:\Source\Development\websites\example.com.au\root' was not found."`

Answer (score 2):

You can use start-process instead of invoke-item, which will give you control of the window size.  You can implement that with miminmal changes to the script by creating an ii function to override the alias temporarily, and then remove it when you're done:

```
function ii { start-process explorer -WindowStyle Maximized -ArgumentList $args[0] }
ii E:\Source\Development\websites\example.com.au\root
ii E:\Source\Development\websites\example.com.au
ii E:\Source\Development\websites\example.com.au\css
ii E:\Source\Development\websites\example.com.au\database
ii E:\Source\Development\websites\example.com.au\js
Remove-Item function:ii
```

Comment: This doesn't work. The first time I ran this I got maximised windows. I then made the windows smaller and then closed them. I ran the script again but this time the windows did not open at maximum but at the last window size setting.