# simulate user input when calling Windows executable

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to pass a password into a Windows executable (simulating user input). Whenever I try to do that I get "no console available for secure input". The executable is an ORACLE executable called cdxdbi.

I am trying to call it like this:

```
CDXDBI.exe < params
```

where params is a file containing the password. Without the paramters the executable brings up a cmd terminal prompting for the password (twice).

How can I inject parameters into the terminal? I do not have more information on the exe, unfortunately. Anyone had the same issue and can provide a solution?

Best regards,
Sebastian

Comment: you can try [nircmd sendkeypress](http://nircmd.nirsoft.net/sendkeypress.html)

Comment: `AutoIt` is another tool you can use.

Comment: vbs or powershell can do sendkeys. Something similar to this might be in order.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21036524/open-folder-and-maximise-the-folder-window

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the following

- CDXDBI is a console based application
- The password prompt is the first and second line reads of stdin

Something like this might work

```
(
    echo Password
    echo Password
)| CDXDBI.exe
```

Otherwise, you will have to use one an external tool like mentioned in the comments.